# Android List Color Scheme

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I am using Eclipse on Mac, and am wondering why the backgrounds on different on these apps.

The one with a solid background is a sample app (Android Basics), and the one with the gradient is mines (Pixnake).

What I want to know is how to make mines solid black? Where do I look?
I removed the theme from mines but that just removed white.

[image: Solid]

[image: Gradient]

Manifest of the gradient, now solid black app:

http://pastebin.com/eCEEE5Uu

Manifest of the solid one, without the hardwareAccelerate tag:

http://pastebin.com/Phqjv2j5

Answer (score 0):

The gradient background is the default for apps in ICS using hardware acceleration (which is the default).  You can turn off hardware acceleration for your app by putting `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in your application tag in your Manifest.

```
<application
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
.../>
```

Should get rid of the gradient.

Comment: That's weird then. The other, solid one, doesn't have that tag. So why does it not have it?

Comment: The other one probably targets an SDK below 11.

Comment: It targets 15, and so does mine. And the hardware accelerate set to false removes the gradient.

Comment: Done. I'm looking at it and still can't figure it out.

EDIT: Figured it out. It was placement of the sdk tag. It had to be after application. Why is this?

Comment: I didn't think the placement of the uses-sdk tag mattered.  I've always put it before the application tag and never had any issues.